# avoid dom container elements when splitting components

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I am using react and I want to split a component in subcomponents, to optimize it ( I am using mobX and trying to achieve something as the list example here https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/react-performance.html )

However by doing so it seems that I am forced in introducing extra dom elements.
Consider a NodeComponent to render a tree

```
const NodeComponent = ({node}) => (
  <div>
    <div that access some stuff with node properties/>
    {children.map(childNode => <NodeComponent node={childNode} />)}
  </div>
);
```

this is pseudocode, i hope you get the idea.

How do I separate the first inner div from the recursive rendering, without introducing an additional wrapper dom element around the children (like the div below) ?

```
const NodeComponent = ({node}) => (
  <div>
    <div that access some stuff with node properties/>
    **<useless div>**
      {children.map(childNode => <NodeComponent node={childNode} />)}
    **<useless /div>**
  </div>
);
```

If I have thousands of nodes, that means thousands of additional useless dom elements, and moreover I am porting an existing control with a specific dom structure and CSS and I have to change it if I want to split them.

TL;DR; can i split this component in 2 so I can get the mobx optimization of not rerendering all the children when it is not necessary without changing the DOM output?

Or again: why a pure optimization/refactoring is obliging me to modify my dom end-result?

Comment: I don't get your problem.. Is there a real problem here?

Comment: tl;dr;: pure splitting/refactoring of react components imposes you to modify the dom because of react's limit of 1 root element per component.

modifying the dom is not a solution if you need to work with existing styles/css or if you have thousands of nodes and you don't want to introduce all those additional dom nodes. In general also I think refactoring your components shouldn't impose you to change their output (the dom). So I am looking for a workaround about it

Comment: You can always split your components into separate functions, without splitting them into separate components

Comment: @mweststrate first of all, thanks for working on MobX, it is awesome and I am trying to push my company to adopt it :)

 I am actually trying to do something similar to your example on how to optimize a list in here: https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/react-performance.html 

are you suggesting to make those separate functions observers themselves, just not components?

Comment: i'll update my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, I will end up using something like https://github.com/mwiencek/react-packages in order to make React/JSX happy and not being obliged to change my dom structure. It's more of a hacky workaround than a proper solution, but it does fix my problem.

Hopefully when https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127 gets fixed I won't need it anymore.

Thanks everybody for the help anyway, I really appreciate it (and thanks once more to @mweststrate for MobX in general :) )

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a recursive data structure. I think you can nicely split this up into multiple components without having unecessary nodes:

```
Node = observer({ node } => (
  <div>
    {node.title}
    <Children={node.children} />
  </div>
))

Children = observer({ children } => (
  !children ? null :
  <ul>
    {children.map(child => <Node node={child} />
  </ul>
))
```

I think that is the most minimal tree you can get and mobx can very well optimize this as the children collection is rendered as separate component. You might have the idea that the `ul` is unneeded, but I think that for all practical styling reasons you will probably need this dom node because otherwise it is really hard to target  descendants without targeting parents.

Besides that, I wouldn't care too much about additional nodes in your DOM without some emperical proof for it being a bottleneck. It might be very well that it doesn't matter at all, or that for example your CSS selectors are a lot faster with the `ul` then without the ul

Comment: Wouldn't a change in the node title rerender all the children in this case?


Anyway I did something similar to what you suggest but the node.title bit in its own component as well so changing anything in the node except the children doesn't rerender the children (as you describe in the mobx docs anyway).


However as said, my problem is that I work with an existing dom/css styling that displays nested divs as separate rows. My problem is that I know how to fix this, but I hate that fixing this obliges me to change my dom/css structure. It might be fine for (...continued)

Comment: (...continued) it might be fine for a small project with a small team but I am dealing with an enterprise application with 30-40 devs and having to change the dom/css styling of your components only as a side effect of a refactoring is not really acceptable. 

I searched a bit and I guess what I really want/need is a proper solution to this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127
I guess for the time being I am going to have a similar workaround of having a fake 'Frag' node that won't be rendered so the jsx transpiler will be happy.

Comment: In general I am not really concerned about performance bottlenecks introduced by those extra elements, I am more concerned of breaking existing styles/behaviour that might rely on that precise dom structure. I don't want to be forced to make dom changes only as a side effect of splitting a component in two.

Of course relying on a precise dom structure is bad , but you often have this constraint while working in big projects/teams anyway.

Comment: No, changing the title won't rerender the children; the contents of the array is not dereferenced in the Node reference, and the Children component will be recycled. So updating the title will just rerender the Node itself.